# cPanel Fixwebalizer Issue

Tags: cpanel

Whenever i am trying to run the script: /usr/local/cpanel/script/fixwebalizer , it is giving me the following error.
Enter Username to fix webalizer for? statxxxx

```
Log checker loaded ok..
==> cPanel Log Daemon version 25.0
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/XSLoader.pm line 70.
at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql.pm line 15
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Logd.pm line 79.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Logd.pm line 79.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/libexec/cpanellogd line 199.
```

If anyone know how to resolve it, your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with perl on your server.

Try in order:

/scripts/checkperlmodules  --full

If don't work:
Try reinstall Perl from layer1.cpanel.net (get [perl588installer.tar.gz](http://layer1.cpanel.net/perl588installer.tar.gz))

Answer (score 0):

Force reinstall the perl modules.  First login to perl shell

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

Force install the below modules.

```
force install DBI
force install DBD::mysql
```